# css value set with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have 12 text boxes some will have no value entered I am trying to create a page for printing the input text. Box with no data can be omitted The problem is setting the css top value so the page printed output is one line after another example
Test each INPUT BOX grab the values THEN use a counter y to increment position solved

```
if ($("#cAA").val() > 0){
var line1 = $("#cLAA").text() + " " + $("#cAA").val() + " " + $("#cLmL1").text();
y = y + 420
//w.push(line1); // To reuse data add to an array!

$("#line1").val(line1).css("position","absolute");
var c1 = $("#line1").css("margin-top",(y)+"px");
$("#line1").val(line1).append(c1);
$("#line1").val(line1).css("left","50px");

//$("#line1").text(w[X]);//To display data on screen
// X = X + 1; // Counter to display array data
$("#line1").append(line1);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps use appendChild on the parent container, rather than doing append on each object?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I am still learning jQuery and I am not sure that will work because each element needs to be tested. I do agree this code is a little fat I am trying to trim it down but will test your concept final result at [link](http://rxkinetics.com/dwight/tpnprint.html)